# Does Blur's song MyTerracotta Heart signal another Blur breakdown?

Tags: meaning, rock, pop

In *Blur*'s latest album *The Magic Whip* there's a song called "My Terracotta Heart" that makes me wonder about the future of the band.

*The Magic Whip* is the new album recorded by *Blur* after 12 years of silence. The last album before *The Magic Whip* is *Think Tank*, the only album recorded without guitarist and co-founder Graham Coxon.

Coxon was "fired" from the band because of his problems with alcohol.
Coxon's alcohol addiction casued lots of frictions between him and the band, specially with Damon Albarn (they were friends before the rise of the band, almost best friends). After his departure from Blur, Coxon and the band entered in a "cold period" during which they didn't talk with each other for many years.

In the 2012, Albarn and Coxon made peace, making the Blur reunion with two gigs at Hyde Park. Then, they came back to work in studio and *The Magic Whip* was the result.

Now, it seems that everything is fine, but listening to the lyrics of "My Terracotta Heart" I think that the relationship between Coxon and Albarn is ruining again.

Here are the words that make me think this:

> Is my terracotta heart breaking?
>
> I don't know If I'm losing you
>
> If I'm losing you again

I think that Albarn uses a terracotta heart as analogy, a metaphor that represent their (delicate, fragile) friendship.

Do "My Terracotta Heart" lyrics talk about that? Did Damon Albarn write this song to say that their delicate friendship is wasting again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The song is about the past](http://www.nme.com/news/blur/83904), explained Coxon to NME:

> In his track by track guide to 'The Magic Whip' for NME, Coxon
>   explained that the track 'My Terracotta Heart' was about his
>   relationship with Albarn.
>
> He admitted: "I knew it was going to be an incredibly sad song, which
>   is why I put the crying guitar on there. What I didn't know at the
>   time was that **the lyrics would turn out to be about Damon and I, our
>   long-term friendship and the ups and downs we’ve had.**"

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Anyway, i think that the Graham Coxon words are misleading, beacuse Albarn sings "If i'm losing you again". It seems that he's talking about now, not about the past, but i think that for marketing reasons, Coxon couldn't admit it.